# Auto-build an Mkdocs documentation in Travis CI

Tags: python, continuous-integration, travis-ci, mkdocs

How exactly do I automatically deploy my Mkdocs documentation in Travis CI?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's how to automatically deploy your mkdocs document. Simply follow the 3 steps below.

#### Step 1

Simply insert the following code snippets into their respective locations in your `.travis.yml` configuration file:

```
language: python # Set the build language to Python

python: 3.8 # Set the version of Python to use

branches: master # Set the branch to build from

install:
    - pip install mkdocs # Install the required dependencies

script: true # Skip script (Don't use this if one already exists)

before_deploy:
    - mkdocs build --verbose --clean --strict # Build a local version of the docs

deploy: # Deploy documentation to Github in the gh_pages branch
    provider: pages
    skip_cleanup: true
    github_token: $github_token
    local_dir: site
    on:
        branch: master
```

#### Step 2

If you are using a mkdocs theme that is not `mkdocs` or `readthedocs` then follow the following steps to install it:

- Scenario 1: The theme is installable via pip (such as [mkdocs-material](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/))

  1. Append `pip install mkdocs` with the other packages you need to install for example with `mkdocs-material` it would be `pip install mkdocs mkdocs-material pymdown-extensions pygments`
- Scenario 2: The theme is **not** installable via pip (such as [docskimmer](https://hfagerlund.github.io/mkdocs-docskimmer/))

  1. Remove the `--strict` argument from `mkdocs build --verbose --clean --strict` to suppress a possible error from using theme not installable via pip.
  2. Add the code required to set up the theme in the `before_deploy` section, above `mkdocs build --verbose --clean`

  The code in the `before_deploy` section would look like this for [docskimmer](https://hfagerlund.github.io/mkdocs-docskimmer/):

  ```
    before_deploy:
        - git clone https://github.com/hfagerlund/mkdocs-docskimmer.git # Clone the repo hosting the code
        - cp -r $PWD/mkdocs-docskimmer/mkdocs_docskimmer . # Copy the required code to the repo root
        - cp -r $PWD/mkdocs-docskimmer/mkdocs_docskimmer/. ./docs # Copy the required code to the docs folder
        - mkdocs build --verbose --clean # Build a local version of the docs
  ```

  > Installation of themes not available via pip may vary.

#### Step 3

The **final** step is to tell Travis CI the credentials required to sign in to your GitHub account to push the changes:

1. If you've already set up a Personal Access token with the `public_repo` scope, skip to step 11
2. Go to [this](https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=public_repo,repo_deployment) URL. If it loads, skip to step 7. Otherwise, continue these instructions as usual.
3. Go to the [settings](https://github.com/settings/profile) of your Github account
4. Click [Developer settings](https://github.com/settings/developers)
5. Click [Personal access tokens](https://github.com/settings/tokens)
6. Click [Generate new token](https://github.com/settings/tokens/new)
7. You may need to enter your GitHub password to authorise the creation
8. Under `Token description`, choose a name for your token - it could be anything; I'd name it something like `Travis CI` as you can reuse the token for as many repositories as you like.
9. Enable the `public_repo` and `repo_deployment` scope/permission
10. Click `Generate token` at the bottom of the page
11. Go to the settings of the Travis CI repository which you want to build the Mkdocs documentation for
12. Create an environmental variable with the following settings:

    - Name: `github_token`
    - Value: `<THE TOKEN YOU JUST GENERATED>`
    - Display value in build log: `No`
13. Click `add`

#### Afterword

You're done! Please feel free to ask me any questions in the comments.

Also, if the method stops working or doesn't work, PLEASE tell me in the comments and I will fix it ASAP.

Comment: It does not work. Travis asks me to `Please override the script: key in your .travis.yml to run tests.`

Comment: I have made an edit that corrects a lot of this, and it has unfortunately gone down into the void. Anyway, you should omit `before_deploy:` and put the mkdocs build commands in `script:`. They result in the same behavior.

Comment: i want to add dev env for documentation website so users will commit documentation to dev n test. Then PR will be raised to master n build will be triggered to gh-pages

Comment: Worked like a charm. But `public_repo` access only failed for me. I need `public_repo` and  `repo_deployment `

Comment: Updated the scope list

Comment: Like a boss! Thanks alot Richie +1

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple to deploy your MkDocs website using Travis
(considered you are using material theme)

Step 1: Create the repository for your project with empty 3 branches called master, dev, gh-pages.

Step 2 : Clone repository and local and checkout to dev branch. 
        Add your MkDocs website to your dev branch on local.
        Add '/site' directory to git-ignore.(ie don't push .html)
        add .travis.yml given below in repo.
        Push you site to dev branch.

Step 3: Raise pull request to master from dev branch

Step 4: Login to Travis and connect your repositories there,
        Add env variable 'git_token' in travis(used in .travis.yml) its value you can get 
        from github.com -> settings-> dev settings -> personal access token.

Step 5: Complete/Merge pull request to master.It will trigger web-hook and Travis will start build.After build your generated html files will be pushed to gh-pages branch.

Step 6: Go to repository settings and setup git-hub pages website to load from gh-pages branch.

Done

.travis.yml

```
language: python # Set the build language to Python

python: 3.6 # Set the version of Python to use

branches: master # Set the branch to build from

install:
    - pip install mkdocs mkdocs-material pymdown-extensions pygments # Install the required dependencies

script: true # Skip script (Don't use this if one already exists)

before_deploy:
    - mkdocs build --verbose --clean --strict # Build a local version of the docs

deploy: # Deploy documentation to Github in the gh_pages branch
    provider: pages
    skip_cleanup: true
    github_token: $github_token
    local_dir: site
    on:
        branch: master
```